# Почему не растягиваются картинки на всю ширину экрана в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, android-xml, glide

В разметке `activity_main` лежит `RecyclerView`. В адаптер я добавляю список картинок. В параметре картинок я указываю ширину `match_parent` и высоту `wrap_content`. Значит по логике картинка должна занять всю ширину экрана, а высота картинки - по содержимому.

Разметка `main_activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка `item_image.xml`, которую я кидаю в адаптер:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
</ImageView>
```

Код `MyAdapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<String> list;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void updateData(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)  {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_image,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String s = list.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(s).into(holder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView image;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            this.image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Код `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        list.add("http://....");
        list.add("http://....");
        list.add("http://....");
        list.add("http://....");
        list.add("http://....");

        myAdapter.updateData(list);
    }
}
```

Прикрепляю картинку для наглядности (розовый цвет `RecyclerView` тоже для наглядности :)). Что я упускаю? Почему приложение ведет себя так, как не должно себя вести по логике? Ведь какие-то картинки растягиваются на всю ширину экрана,
 а какие-то нет. [image: картинка]

Comment: Может ширина картинки меньше ширины экрана?

Comment: `centerCrop()` или `fitCenter()` в Glide попробуйте.

Comment: @post_zeew Зациклил добавление картинок. Так вот те же самые "ромашка" и "котик", которые на скрине где-то  попадаются на всю ширину экрана, а где-то как на скрине

Comment: @post_zeew или вот сейчас пробую. 2-ая картинка в ресайкле отображается на всю ширину экрана, я листаю ресайкл вниз, потом поднимаю его обратно до видимости 2 картинки, а она уже отображается как на скрине. Бред какой-то

Comment: @ahgpoug попробовал. аналогичная проблема

Comment: Попробуйте добавить параметр `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` к ImageView.

Comment: Покажите код разметки `activity_main`

Comment: @McDaggen добавил к вопросу.

Comment: @eugeneek вы гений!!! Огромное спасибо! не понимаю, почему с моими разнообразными запросами в гугл, я не нашел данный ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно установить атрибут у `ImageView` [`android:adjustViewBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) в `true`. Тогда `ImageView` будет подстраивать свои границы с сохранением соотношения сторон картинки.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    ...
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    ... 
/>
```

Comment: Столько кода скопипастил сюда, а решение моего вопроса - всего лишь одна строка :) Программирование - прикольная штука, однако)